# Does Siva reside In the Sun?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, sandhyavandanam

Are there verses praising Siva as residing within the Sun like there are statments for Vishnu regarding the same?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the eight forms (Ashtamurti) of Lord Shiva?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21725/what-are-the-eight-forms-ashtamurti-of-lord-shiva)

Answer (score 10):

The Sun which is seen in the sky above is directly told as having darshan of Lord Shiva in Veda **Samhitas**. In the first Anuvaka of Sri Rudram we have:

> असौ यस्ताम्रो अरुण उत बभ्रुस्सुमङ्गलः  । .... असौ योsवसर्पति नीलग्रीवो विलोहितः । उतैनं गोपा अदृशन्नदृशन्नुदहार्यः ॥ उतैनं विश्वा भूतानि स दृष्टो मृडयाति नः ॥ (Yajurveda 4.5.1)
>
> This Sun who is copper-red when he arises, then golden-yellow, this highly auspicious and beneficent one is truly him. The Nilagriva Rudra **who has assumed the form of the sun** that glows red when rising. **Him the cowherds, the women carrying water, and all the creatures behold.** He, who is seen by all, let Him send happiness to us.

Similarly in the **Brahmanas** of Vedas as described in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21725/what-are-the-eight-forms-ashtamurti-of-lord-shiva/21728#21728).

> He answered, ‘ You are Mahadeva’ **Since the sun is Mahadeva**, thereby the Mahadeva harms him not, nor his offspring, nor his cattle, nor any one claiming to he his.... (Rigveda Kausitki Brahmana chapter 6)

Similarly in **Upanishad** also like:

> यो वै रुद्रः स भगवान्यश्च सूर्यस्तस्मै वै नमोनमः ॥ ७॥ (Atharvasiras)
>
> He who is **Rudra**, He is Bhagavan, He is **in the form of Sun**, Salutations to him

Similarly in multiple **Puranas** as described in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10524/whats-the-relation-between-lord-shiva-and-lord-shani-dev/17075#17075).

> रुद्र इत्युच्यते देवैर्भगवान् भुक्तिमुक्तिदः ।
> सूर्यात्मकस्य रुद्रस्य भक्तानां भक्तदायिनः ।।
> सुवर्चला स्मृता देवी सुतश्चास्य शनैश्चरः ।
> समस्तसौम्यवस्तुनां प्रकृतित्वेन विश्रुतः ।। (Linga Purana)
>
> **The Lord in the form of Sun is called Rudra by the Gods**. In the form of sun he bestows prosperity to all and yields all the worldly pleasures and salvation. **When he becomes Sun** then his Godesses is Suvarchala and their son is Saturn (Sanaishchara).
>
> सूर्यों जल मही वहिर्वायुराकाशमेव च।
> दीक्षितो ब्राह्मणः सोम इत्येतास्तनवः क्रमात्॥७॥
> सुवर्चला तथैवोमा सुकेशी चापरा शिवा।
> स्वाहा दिशस्तथा दीक्षा रोहणी च यथाक्रमम् ॥८॥ (Vishnu Purana)
>
> He also assigned to them their respective stations, **the Sun**, water, ether, air, fire, earth, the ministrant Brahman, and the moon; **for these are their several forms.** The wives of the Sun and the other manifestations, termed Rudra and the rest were respectively, Suvercalā, Uma, Vikesi, Sivā, Svāhā, Dišā, Diksā and Rohiņī.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

> **Vyasa-Gita , Kurma Purana II.29.39**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Bhagawan Shiva reside in the Sun plus he is also the Sun as we see it.

> *"He said to him, 'Thou art Îsâna (the Ruler).' And because he gave him that name, the Sun became suchlike, **for Îsâna is the Sun,** since the Sun rules over this All. He said, 'So great indeed I am: give me no other name after that!' **(Shatapatha Brahmana 6:1:3.17).***

> *Then, [worship of the effulgent being in the sun]: The white glow of the sun is sā, and the dark bluish-black glow is ama. These two together make up the word Sama.**There is a deity within the orb of the sun, who is seen by the yogis. His whole body glitters like gold, even to his toe-nails. He has a bright golden beard and bright golden hair. **(Chandogya Upanishad 1.6.6).*****

> ***Salutations again and again to the Golden armed, to the the golden hued One, whose form is resplendent like Gold, who is the Lord of Gold,** who is the Lord of Ambika, of Uma, who is the Lord of Pashus”~ **(Taittiriya Aranyaka 10.22.1).***

> ***I know the great Purusha (Rudra), who is having sun like luster and is beyond darkness.** Only by knowing him one overcomes death, there is no other way to supreme goal. **(Svetasvatara Upanishad 3:08).***

> *When there is complete absence of the darkness of ignorance, then what is experienced is neither day nor night; neither existence or non-existence; **the Supreme Lord Shiva alone exists as pure; that is indestructible; that is adorable light and the deity of even Savitar (Sun) himself;** from that this ancient wisdom proceeded all over the world”. **(Shvetashvatara Upanishad 4.18).***

> ***“This Sun who is copper-red when he arises, then golden-yellow, this highly auspicious and beneficent one is truly Rudra.** These other Rudras who are quartered round about in all directions of this earth, may I ward off their anger by my praise”.  **(Yajurveda Sri Rudram – Anuvaka -1).***

> ***“The black-throated Rudra who has assumed the form of the sun that glows red when rising.** Him the cowherds, the women carrying water, and all the creatures behold. He, who is seen by all, let Him send happiness to us”. **(Yajurveda Sri Rudram – Anuvaka -1) .***

For more you can see [this answer of mine.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/54210/20968)

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Answer (score 0):

Garuda purana mentions the worship of Suryarupi Shiva through surya mantras. Thus, it is established that Siva resides in the sun.

**Garuda Purana  Acharakhanda Chapter 23**

[image]